# For loop that gets the indexes in JSON array

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function to create a device from an API.

```
    for($i=0;$i < count($response); $i++)
    {
        $device = Device::create([
            'device_id' => $response['devices'][$i]['device_id'],
            'source_id' => Device::getSource($options['deviceSourceId'])->id,
            'alias' => $response['devices'][$i]['alias'],
            'online_state' => $response['devices'][$i]['online_state'],
        ]);
    }
```

And this is the raw JSON data.

[JSON DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mxrH.jpg)

It needs to get the data from every device from the JSON response and create a device. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Wait, isn't your code is pulling the data from every devices already?

Comment: @LionelChan It's pulling from the JSON response. When I change the $i to 1 or 0 it pulls one of them.

Comment: I guess you need to change the count to `count($response['devices'])`?

Comment: Also, `Device::getSource($options['deviceSourceId'])->id` is static. Consider put it outside the for loop. And consider using a foreach so you don't need to use `$i` (redundant in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are working with an array of objects. You could use `foreach` like so:

```
// get device source id outside the loop
$deviceSourceId = Device::getSource($options['deviceSourceId'])->id;

foreach($response->devices as $device) {
    // No need to set a variable if you are not using it
    Device::create([
        'device_id' => $device->device_id,
        'source_id' => $deviceSourceId,
        'alias' => $device->alias,
        'online_state' => $device->online_state,
    ]);
}
```